# What does init mean in c# 9?

Tags: c#

I have come across with "**init**" keyword in c# in the C# 9 preview. What does it mean and what are its applications?

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly string firstName;
    private readonly string lastName;

    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get => firstName; 
        init => firstName = (value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(FirstName)));
    }
    public string LastName 
    { 
        get => lastName; 
        init => lastName = (value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(LastName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The init keyword creates so called Init Only Setters. They add the concept of init only properties and indexers to C#. These properties and indexers can be set at the point of object creation but become effectively get only once object creation has completed.

The main reason for the introduction is to avoid boilerplate code.

A simple immutable object like Point requires:

```
struct Point
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

The init accessor makes immutable objects more flexible by allowing the caller to mutate the members during the act of construction. That means the object's immutable properties can participate in object initializers and thus removes the need for all constructor boilerplate in the type. The Point type is now simply:

```
struct Point
{
    public int X { get; init; }
    public int Y { get; init; }
}
```

The consumer can then use object initializers to create the object

```
var p = new Point() { X = 42, Y = 13 };
```

You can read the proposal with more details and explanation here:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/c2df2ee72f4b36fca2e07c701a90a0dba8d1fc20/proposals/init.md

Comment: "by allowing the caller to mutate the members during the act of construction" - Sorry for nitpicking, but this should read "...the members during the act of initialization", not *during* construction, as the init-only properties are invoked _after_ the type's constructor has completed and _before_ the assignment is made.

Comment: "The consumer can then use object initializers to create the object" why is this specific about init? I am able to do this with set as well.

Comment: I'm unclear on one thing. While I understand your answer, I don't understand how it differs from `public int Number{get;}`, i.e. with no setter at all. That way, we can still set the value using `new Thing{Number=1337}` and have it read-only. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The init is like the old 'set' but you are only allowed to use it on creation/initialization of the class.

Like:

```
var p = new Person { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "West" };
```

After that you are not allowed to change FirstName or LastName.

This will throw an expection:

```
var p = new Person();
p.FirstName = "Adam";
```

Comment: It will be a great feature permitting developers to use read-only properties more effectively.

Comment: Will it be an exception or a compile time error? As far as I read the proposal, it's an error, which is way better than an exception.

Comment: As you mention, according to the proposal it only mention error but gives no more details. But i would guess it would work like the rest of the setters today, if you only use a get (without a set) you would get an instant error as i hope this would work as well.