# Setting init-only properties when using Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, constructor, properties, init-only

C# 9.0 introduced init-only class properties feature but they can't be used when creating instances by class type with Activator.CreateInstance. A simplistic example:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}

void Test()
{
    Person person = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
    person.Name = "Bob"; // Doesn't work
}
```

Looking for some solution other than using constructor arguments (too many of them).

Comment: In that particular code why would you use `Activator` anyway? Or rather: if you know the type then why use `Activator`, and if you don't know the type and are using reflection, how would you even attempt to set the property without reflection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C#9, how do init-only properties differ from read-only properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749277/in-c9-how-do-init-only-properties-differ-from-read-only-properties) and [What is difference between Init-Only and ReadOnly in C# 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372422/what-is-difference-between-init-only-and-readonly-in-c-sharp-9) and [What does init mean in c# 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228994/what-does-init-mean-in-c-sharp-9)

Comment: There is a solution down in the discussion indeed, but David gave straight answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Init properties are settable only in the following [contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init#init-accessors):

- During an object initializer
- During a `with` expression initializer
- Inside an instance constructor of the containing or derived type, on `this` or `base`
- Inside the `init` accessor of any property, on `this` or `base`
- Inside attribute usages with named parameters

In turn, Object Initialization is simply syntactic sugar to set the instance properties or fields without directly invoking the constructor, and essentially transforms from

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "Bob" };
```

to

```
Person person2 = new Person();
person2.Name = "test";
Person person = person;
```

When using `Activator.CreateInstance`, you bypass this syntactic sugar.  That said, if you are already using `Activator.CreateInstance`, you are potentially comfortable taking additional reflection hits.  You can simply call `PropertyInfo.SetValue` to set the values after object creation:

```
Person person = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
    
person.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(person, "Bob");
```

Alternatively, you can create constructors and pass the values to the constructor.

Comment: Reflection hit is okay. But it's interesting that this method allows setting the init-only property several times and at any time.

Comment: Reflection allows you to modify something at runtime without any of the restrictions that are provided by the compiler. Init is a compiler concept, not an IL or runtime concept. As a result, once you are passed compilation, you can change the object state as much as you like.

Answer (score -3):

Init should be initialized in the construction of the object and therefore you should initialize its value in the constructor. You can do it this way:

```
(Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person), "Bob");
```

Note, you need to add an appropriate constructor.

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }        

    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: This is one way, but as I wrote it's not preferred solution as there are many constructor arguments.